# Starcraft 2: can you permanently display the frames-per-second?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2, you can display the frames-per-second by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> but then it goes away in after the current game ends.

**Can you permanently display the frames-per-second?**

Comment: do you really need to display the frames-per-second when not ingame?

Comment: ^ That's not what he wants. The game only show the FPS counter for ONE game. When you quit it disappears and doesn't come back until you manually activate it again.

Comment: @CoqPwner, oh, right... I'll have a look about that and post an answer when I got one

Comment: @CoqPwner is correct in interpreting the question. I just want the FPS to always be displayed, when playing a game (doesn't matter when I'm not in a game navigating menus), so that when the FPS gets low I can adjust my settings or go fix whatever is slowing down my computer.

Comment: @syn1kk I may ask: do you run the game from the bnet application or from it's own executable?

Comment: @gl_prout i was launching through the windows start menu "StarCraft 2". and that opens battle.net app which i then have to click "play" button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that by configuring the game using the battle.net client, check the "Additional command line argument" checkbox.

And in the input that appears, you can enter `-showfps=1`.

If you don't launch the game using the battle.net client, you can try editing the properties of the shortcut you use to launch the game by adding that argument after the path of the game.

I tested it yesterday, it seems to work. The only time the info disappears is when you are on the loading screen, where there are Kerrigan, Raynor and Artanis's faces, and it reappears on the next screen.

You can make it disappear anytime by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> again.

Comment: i was using the battle.net app to launch sc2. i just tried your solution and the command line args work perfectly! clicking the "Additional command line argument" was easy.

Comment: I'm glad I understood the question then